# Add Ruby Source Code as HTML to RDoc

Tags: ruby, rake, rdoc, rakefile

**How do I include a ruby code file, as is, into RDoc?**

I have an example.rb file that documents how to use my gem and I would like to include that as one of the files like the README.rdoc and HISTORY.rdoc.

I've already figured out how to convert the ruby source code into HTML using the [Syntax gem](http://syntax.rubyforge.org/) but I can't figure out how to make RDoc include the file without parsing it.

When I tell RDoc to include the html file it isn't listed and if I fake it out by using rdoc or txt as the file extension it doesn't display properly (the file is still actually html).

I've got a solution that works it's just incredibly ugly. There has got to be a better way to do this that's native to rdoc but I don't see it.

Here's what I have in my Rakefile:

```
# Build rdocs
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'syntax/convertors/html'
rdoc_dir = 'rdoc'
# This is rdoc1 but it doesn't work unless you DON'T wrap it in a task
# Generate html files from example ruby files
convertor = Syntax::Convertors::HTML.for_syntax "ruby"
replacement_key = "REPLACE_THIS_TEXT_WITH_PROPER_HTML"
# Create dummy files
Dir.glob('examples/*.rb').each do |file|
  File.open("#{file}.txt", "w") do |dummy_file|
    dummy_file.write(replacement_key)
  end
end

# Call the rdoc task
Rake::RDocTask.new(:rdoc2) do |rdoc|
  rdoc.rdoc_dir = rdoc_dir
  rdoc.title = "pickled_optparse #{version}"
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README*')
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('HISTORY*')
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('examples/*.txt')
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
end

task :rdoc3 do
  # Now use a hammer to replace the dummy text with the
  # html we want to use in our ruby example code file.
  html_header = File.read('rake_reqs/html_header.html')
  Dir.glob('examples/*.rb').each do |file|
    html_ruby = convertor.convert(File.read(file))
    rdoc_file = "#{rdoc_dir}/examples/#{File.basename(file,".rb")}_rb_txt.html"
    fixed_html = File.read(rdoc_file).gsub!(replacement_key, "#{html_header}#{html_ruby}")
    File.open(rdoc_file, "w") {|f| f.write(fixed_html)}
    File.delete("#{file}.txt")
  end
end

task :rdoc => [:rdoc2, :rdoc3]
```

Comment: Is the project available publicly?  Github perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, this is part of my pickled_optparse project https://github.com/PicklePumpers/pickled_optparse and you can install the gem from RubyGems.org using "gem install pickled_optparse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't give you an actual answer but I'm looking at [sdoc](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc) myself. 
You can install the [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/sdoc) from ruby gems.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking at that too. I don't think there is a real answer to this so you get the "answered" just for trying ;)